# UI Button and clone object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to the unit and I still don't know a lot, and I am still trying to figure it out in many ways, so please do not swear.
The first project I decided to make Tetris and I had a problem. I am trying to make control of figures through the UI Button and the problem is that the control does not work with the clones that I create through Instantiate, however, with the original object, if I just transfer it to the stage, the control works quietly. How to make the UI Button work the same for clones? Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Group : MonoBehaviour
{
    float lastFall = 0;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (!isValidGridPos())
        {
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }      
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Move Left
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

            if (isValidGridPos())
            {
                updateGrid();
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            }
        }



        // Move Right
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

            if (isValidGridPos())
            {
                updateGrid();
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        // Rotate
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);

            if (isValidGridPos())
            {
                updateGrid();
            }
            else
            {
                transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
            }
        }

        //Down
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) ||
                 Time.time - lastFall >= 1)
        {

            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);

            if (isValidGridPos())
            {
                updateGrid();
            }
            else
            { 
                transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
                Playfield.deleteFullRows();
                FindObjectOfType<Spawner>().SpawnNext();
                enabled = false;
            }
            lastFall = Time.time;
        }
    }


    bool isValidGridPos()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            Vector2 v = Playfield.roundVec2(child.position);

            if (!Playfield.insideBorder(v))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (Playfield.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y] != null &&
                Playfield.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y].parent != transform)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void updateGrid()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Playfield.h; ++y)
            for (int x = 0; x < Playfield.w; ++x)
                if (Playfield.grid[x, y] != null)
                    if (Playfield.grid[x, y].parent == transform)
                        Playfield.grid[x, y] = null;

        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            Vector2 v = Playfield.roundVec2(child.position);
            Playfield.grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y] = child;
        }
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

        if (isValidGridPos())
        {
            updateGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {      
        transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

        if (isValidGridPos())
        {
            updateGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
        }
        
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {            
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);

        if (isValidGridPos())
        {
            updateGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
        }
        
    }

    public void MoveDown()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);

        if (isValidGridPos())
        {
            updateGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            Playfield.deleteFullRows();
            FindObjectOfType<Spawner>().SpawnNext();
            enabled = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are Rotate, MoveLeft etc called from?

Comment: From this script, the MoveLeft () methods, etc. I have attached this script to the prefabs of the figures that need to be controlled during the game. And actually I hung the prefabs themselves on the button, where OnClick () is, and there I call the MoveLeft () method and the rest, but this all does not work with clones. Sory for my english

Comment: Well are the clones ever added as listeners to your buttons? It sounds like you only reference the methods of one object as listeners so the `onClick` will always move the same object ... Sounds like you would rather want to have one central controller instance handling all the user Input and rather store which is the currently active tile (always the last that was instantiated) so the controller moves only that one

Comment: Not exactly one, each method has its own button and yes, I tried to pause the simulation and add the just appeared clone to the button, and then it began to react for pressing the button. But I don't know how these clones will be initially addressed to me, because they are created only after the start of the game (the start of the simulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI I check what you said and if I understand it you lose reference to a new object and cant move it I made a sample code you can try and check it

```
public Transform currentObject;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (currentObject != null)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            currentObject.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0)*Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            currentObject.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            currentObject.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            currentObject.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
public void SetCurrentObj(Transform obj){     currentObject = obj;}
```

//to create cube every 10 sec and you can controll it

```
public GameObject prefab;
public float tik;
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Time.time>tik)
    {
        GameObject temp = Instantiate(prefab,transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
        FindObjectOfType<Controller>().SetCurrentObj(temp.transform);
        tik = Time.time + 10;
    }
}
```